# Add 'Search Wikipedia' and Search 'Physics Forum' for Right-Click-Highlight-Menu?

Tags: firefox, search

Whenever i Highlight and Right-click some word in Firefox in a web page or an Ebook, I see an option 'Search Google'

[image]

I wanted to add 'Search Wikipedia' and search 'Physics Forum' option to it, How can I do it?, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with an add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/context-search/

I googled for "firefox content menu search" and got several possibilities.

Comment: i dont want it on just on a browser, i want it on an ebook of pdf file also